# How to handle activity routing with Branch.io?

Tags: android, branch.io

We use Branch to provide our users with a custom experience when the app is launched/installed from a custom URL. This custom experience has to be available to new users (the ones that download the app and sign up for the first time) and to signed in users who already have the app installed.

This custom experience is mandatory for us. If the users clicks on this URL he HAS to be prompted correctly.

We have two activities:

**Activity A** is the launcher activity. 
It serves as a routing activity. Meaning it will look locally if the user is logged in or prompts him with the classical sign in and sign up buttons.

**Activity B** is the home activity. 
It is launched by Activity A when:
- User is already logged in
- User signs in
- User signs up
This is where the "custom" experience happens (the user is prompted with a dialog whenever he gets into the app after clicking the URL).

In **Activity A** I use the following method to retrieve Branch-provided information in onStart():

```
 branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error)
            {
                 // Searches through the JSONObject for key/value pairs...
            }
        };
```

In parallel, I launch a Handler/Runnable pair which serves as a timeout whenever the callback takes too long to be triggered (ie: when the network is very slow). This prevent the splash screen to be displayed for minutes if something goes wrong.

But by doing this I don't feel that I am doing things the good way.

Let's assume that my timeout for the splashscreen is set to 10 seconds and that the callback is only called after 15 seconds. If the user is already logged in he will be redirected to **Activity B** as soon as the 10 seconds are over in **Activity A**. Therefore he will never be prompted with the dialog on the Home screen.

What is the correct way to handle activity routing when routing depends on an async work that can last for n seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Branch should report an error after 5 seconds if the session fails (the callback), in onInit you could check `BranchError error` to see if it's null, and if it isn't then act accordingly. This would remove the need for an independent runnable firing off after 10 seconds.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: In my case Branch can run for minutes before triggering an error if I'm on 2G (Edge).

Comment: Hi Aymeric, please submit a ticket directly to Branch (with information about what app you're testing with) and your issue will be diagnosed. https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new